# Generate timestamp between 2 values

Tags: bash, shell-script, date, timestamps

Im trying to generate a timestamp series between 2 timestamp values with 30mins interval.

Here is what I already prepared.

```
start_ts='2021-08-07 15:00:00'
end_ts='2021-08-11 05:00:00'

while ! [[ $start_ts > $end_ts ]]; do
    echo $start_ts
    start_ts=$(date -d "$start_ts + 30 minutes" +"%Y%m%d% H%:%M:%S")
done
```

But Im getting this error.

```
date: invalid date ‘ 2021-08-07 15:00:00 + 30 minutes’
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your particular problem is that the `+ 30` is interpreted as an invalid time zone.

You could fix that by working in UTC time (which would also avoid problems around DST changes) and use:

```
date -ud "$start_ts +0 + 30 minutes" +'%Y%m%d %T'
```

(note the +0 to specify a timezone with 0 offset to UTC so the next `+30 minute` is interpreted as offset).

Or, to still work with local time, insert `today` or `now` after the timestamp, to make sure what follows is interpreted as offset:

```
date -d "$start_ts now + 30 minutes" +'%Y%m%d %T'
```

Though here, while you're at using GNU-specific extensions, you could do:

```
start_ts=$(date -ud '2021-08-07 15:00:00' +%s)
end_ts=$(date -ud '2021-08-11 05:00:00' +%s)

seq -f "@%.0f" "$start_ts" "$((30 * 60))" "$end_ts" |
  date -uf - +'%Y%m%d %T'
```

To avoid running one `date` per timestamp. Note that `seq` is not a standard command, but as you have GNU `date`, you'll also have GNU `seq` which is part of the same GNU software bundle (`coreutils`).

Or use the zsh shell which has builtin support for timestamp parsing and formatting which would avoid the dependency on GNU `date`:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
zmodload zsh/datetime

format='%Y%m%d %T'
TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs start_ts $format '20210807 15:00:00'
TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs end_ts   $format '20210811 05:00:00'
for ((t = start_ts; t <= end_ts; t += 30 * 60))
  TZ=UTC0 strftime $format $t
```

Beware those may generate timestamps that don't correspond to any time in your timezone. For instance, in mainland UK here, there was no `2021-03-28 01:30:00`, because on that day we switched to summer time, so wallclock time jumped from 00:59:59.99 straight to 02:00:00.00. Conversely, on 2021-10-31, timestamps from 01:00:00 to 02:00:00 will occur twice. Still those codes above on that day, will iterate on 00:30:00, 01:00:00, 01:30:00, 02:00:00, 02:30:00 without going over the 01:00 -> 02:00 interval twice.

If that's not what you want, you should remove the parts that make it work with UTC time (the `-u`, `+0` and `TZ=UTC0`), but then your format should include the timezone offset (`%z`) to make the timestamps non-ambiguous (assuming you timezone offset is always a whole number of minutes which should be the case everywhere these days).